# Xcode Program Not Executing

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I have a program that I am building in Xcode that is built successfully, but after it is built a box appears that says "error: ::posix_spawnp ( pid => 399, path = '/Users/toddbaker/Documents/Poker/Build/Poker/Build/Products/Debug/Poker', file_actions = 0x115880c98, attr = 0x115880cd8, argv = 0x7fab5627d5f0, envp = 0x7fab5628f600 ) err = Permission denied (0x0000000d)".

My program has the files main.cpp, Deck.cpp, Deck.h, Card.cpp, and Card.h. It is going to be a basic Poker program. Does anyone have any idea why I might be getting this error? If my program is built correctly, then why am I getting an error?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Are you getting "Permission Denied" on the machine you built it on, or did you build it and copy it to another machine?  Are you trying to run it from Xcode or are you trying to run it from Terminal.app's command line?

Comment: I'm trying to run it from Xcode and the error pops up after it is built successfully, but before the program can be run.

Comment: It is on the machine that I built it on.

Comment: @ToddBaker I am having the same problem Have you found any solution ? Thanks